# How to control the shape of the range input knob in Firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox, html-input

> *Warning: The original question text below is misleading.*
>
> *In fact appearance of the range input control did not change in Firefox 33.0.2.*

---

The HTML5 range input control:

```html
<input type="range" />
```

used to look roughly like this in Firefox:
[image: The great Firefox range control appearance]

Since the latest update, v33.0.2, it looks like this:
[image]

The original design matched our website's look and feel perfectly. The current one looks pretty much out of place.

Is there a way (CSS or a Firefox configuration setting) to force the original pointy appearance?

Comment: You might have a look at this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081 (section "Styles")

Comment: @M.Page It reads, "Opera and Firefox will only show a standard range slider, unfortunately." Which appears to be outdated becase Firefox seems to support [`::-moz-range-track` and `::-moz-range-thumb`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:Jonathan_Watt/range). They don't tell if it's possible to control the shape though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearance of the Range input control did not actually change in Firefox 33.0.2 - sorry for the confusion.

What happened was that a `border:` CSS rule was accidentally applied to `input[type="range"]`, which did not manifest itself as a visible border because it was later reset with a `border: initial`.

The mere fact that a border was applied put the range control into a themed mode where it would draw a round knob (I wasn't aware of this mode).

The solution is to make sure `border:` is not applied to the control in the first place. Then it will look pointy as it should.

Answer (score 2):

See http://demosthenes.info/blog/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input.

You can do things like

```
::-webkit-slider-thumb, ::-moz-range-thumb, ::-ms-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #666;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
 }
```

Also possibly helpful: http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html, http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/09/how-to-style-range-sliders-in-webkit/, https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334, http://www.htmllion.com/html5-range-input-with-css.html, http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-range-slider-style/, etc. ec.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `::-moz-range-track` pseudo selector and `::-moz-range-thumb` pseudo selector. According to [this site](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html), you'll also need to give `input[type=range]` the same width as your track selector.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qm0kg03/)**

**CSS:**

```
input[type=range] {
    width: 300px;
    }
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    background: #dedede;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 510px 510px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting - it would appear that assigning the `background` `::-moz-range-track` makes the knob round, and removing the styles from `::-moz-range-track` completely makes it pointy again. I'm pretty sure I did not apply any styles to that element. So there should be something else that applied it, I will need to have a look.

Comment: Thank you for a hint in the right direction, I have found the problem.